# Custom code analysis for visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, code-analysis, .net-framework-version

I have created a sample custom rule for database code analysis with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/walkthrough-author-custom-static-code-analysis-rule-assembly?view=sql-server-2017) link help

But in this link given path to paste assembly file (SampleRule.dll) that is `\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120\Extensions` is not available. I am not able to see my custom rule in sql db project.

How can I see my Rule Samples in new sqldb project?

Comment: Do a search in program files (86) for file ScriptDom.dll.  It may be in a different folder depending on version of software on your PC.

Comment: Searched that script file and putted my sample file there but still not able to see my Rule Samples in new sqldb project.

Comment: The path should match the location of the file.  Do not move file.  There are other files in the path that are needed.

Comment: now i got the path but still my sample rule is not visible.

Comment: Try the steps under : Starting a New Visual Studio Session and Creating a Database Project

Comment: I applied everthing that is mentioned in this article